# Is there an off-line way to copy all the extensions from one person profile to another in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have added a person to my Google Chrome set-up and would like to get exactly the same set of extensions as the first person has. Is there a way to clone the set-up without the "log-in to Chrome" feature and any other on-line facilities?

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume that we are running under Windows? If not, the paths may differ, but the concept is still the same.

All of Chrome's data is stored under

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

In here, there will be a bunch of directories, if you have a single user, you want the `Default` directory, if not, there will be a directory for each profile you have.

In these profile directories, there will be a few other directories related to the extensions:

```
Extensions
Extension Rules
Extension State
```

To copy just the extensions to another user, copy just the `Extension` directory from one profile to the other.

If you wish to preserve all settings as well, copy all three.